# Bitrix, AJAX, main.feedback отправка формы

Tags: php, ajax, битрикс

Создал всплывающую форму обратной связи, создав свой компонент на основе main.feedback.
Подключил его в футере с параметрами

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "seoru:main.feedback", 
    "home_feedback", 
    array(
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "home_feedback",
        "USE_CAPTCHA" => "Y",
        "OK_TEXT" => "Спасибо, ваше сообщение принято.",
        "EMAIL_TO" => "eliseevDDDD@gmail.com",
        "REQUIRED_FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "EMAIL",
            1 => "PHONE",
        ),
        "EVENT_MESSAGE_ID" => array(
            0 => "7",
        ),
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_MODE" => "A",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_TYPE" => "DYNAMIC_WITH_STUB",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "Y",  // режим AJAX
        "AJAX_OPTION_SHADOW" => "Y", // затемнять область
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N", // скроллить страницу до компонента.
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y", // подключать стили
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    ),
    false
);?>
```

Но столкнулся с проблемой, что при заполнении всех полей и отправкой формы(на почту все приходит), не выводиться ответ об успешной отправке, а при ошибки в валидации формы(заполнение обязательных полей), не выводятся ошибки, а просто закрывается форма. Может кто фиксил сей баг.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт, то действует. Только у меня была всплывающая форма, div со скрытым модальным окном выводим за пределы шаблона компонента, оставляя в шаблоне только форму. После такой манипуляции все сработало.